# HTML5 video streaming to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am new to frontend/javascript development. Is there any simple solution to stream a HTML5 MediaDevice stream to flask? I have a simple flask server running, which does image processing via OpenCV and outputs the result as a jpeg stream.

Currently, I am using a USB camera as input device, but I want to use a web based solution. Overall, the input should be captured in the browser, send to the server for processing, and finally transferred back to the client.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did u get this to work? if so can you also add the flask code in the question

Answer (score 1):

https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

well, this will give you a little idea how to proceed, I found your question while searching solution for myself.

further steps will include sending frames to the flask server -> processing image -> returning image -> displaying frames by javascript/HTML as shown in the above article.

hope this will help